# Ratio of fruits

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, word-problem

This is a very interesting [Diophantine equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) word problem that I came across in an old textbook of mine. It is quite nice and I decided I would share it with MSE for future reference and a fun time?! So anyway I figured out the answer and posted it below so you can see (This is a Q&A post). So without further ado, the question is:

> The ratio of the number of apples to oranges to pears is 7:11:9. 
>   Timmy ate 21 fruits.
>
> As a result, the ratio of the number of apples to oranges to pears 
>   became 2:3:3. How many fruits were left ?

Any further hints and alternate methods to the one below would be greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Nice, but why answer your own question?

Comment: @Kbot Sorry, I simply found it quite interesting and decided to put it up here in MSE so others and find it for reference. Also, it says answering your  own questions is explicitly encourages in the FAQ section.

Comment: I was just wondering, because I'm pretty new here too.

Comment: @Kbot right there ok. If you like my question or answer, you can always upvote it? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we won't be dealing in fractions here, the total number of fruits
to begin with ($B$) must be a multiple of 7+11+9 = 27 and after Timmy pigs
out, a multiple of 8 ($A$). That is because 7, 11, and 9 have no common
factors, nor do 2 and 3.

Let $B$ = 27$b$ and A = 8$a$.

27$b$ - 21 = 8$a$

We need to solve this Diophantine Equation in integers.

$b$ = 
$\frac{8a + 21}{27}$

27 = 3 × 3 × 3, so 8a + 21 must be divisible by 3,

21 is a multiple of 3, so 8$a$ must also be a multiple of 3.

Therefore a must be a multiple of 3.

Trying various multiples of 3, we find that the lowest value of a that
makes this come out in integers is 21.

(There are better ways of doing this, but in this case the slow method
works because the numbers are small enough.)

$a$ = 21, means there were 168 fruits left (8$a$):

42 apples, 63 oranges, 63 pears (2$a$, 3$a$, 3$a$)

Adding the 21 fruits Timmy ate, makes 189 fruits

$\frac{189}{27}$ 
= 7, so $b$ = 7

49 apples, 77 oranges, 63 pears. (7$b$, 11$b$, 9$b$)

He ate 7 apples, 14 oranges, and 0 pears.